# jquery Ui Dialog can't fadeout twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, dialog

i have a strange problem with jquery 
i have this div that shows messages for ajaxified actions and i want the message to go away when after 5 seconds .. it works for the first time.. but when i trigger the action again in the same page the dialog appears but and never get fade out no matter what unless i close it by press the X button ..  the code is

```
    jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog("close");
}, 5000);

    },
hide: "fadeOut"
});
```

and it's included in a jsp page that include in all ajax pages..what is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it anyway.. i should remove the dialog div everytime it closed looks dirty work but in get a good result

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/) blog entry from nemikor (as stated on the jquery-dialog [page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/))

Every time you call that code snippet, jquery tries to create a new `dialog`-instance with id `dialog`. Create that dialog on start up with the `autoOpen` option set to false and display the dialog by calling `dialog('open')`

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjgw3/)

Comment: yes i got this ..that why i removed the div it created it on close.. but you solution is neat more..thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Add autoOpen:false and open manually each time.  This code is simple and should work fine. Replace "ELEMENTID" with the ID of your dialog.

```
$("#ELEMENTID").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});
$("#ELEMENTID").dialog("open");
```